# docker-compose on windows directory sync

Tags: django, windows, docker, docker-compose

Running the [django tutorial for docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/), but the command to init the django project is not working as expected.

```
$ docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .
[31mERROR[0m: Interactive mode is not yet supported on Windows.
Please pass the -d flag when using `docker-compose run`.
```

In windows "interactive" mode is not supported so I modified the command to run in "detached" mode.

```
$ docker-compose run -d web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .
Creating network "djangotest_default" with the default driver
...
Successfully built 0fb90648c1d8
[33mWARNING[0m: Image for service web was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
djangotest_web_run_1
```

This seems to create the boxes.. but my current directory shows no new files (from the django-admin command).

```
$ ls
docker-compose.yml  Dockerfile  requirements.txt
```

How do I get the container output to sync with the current working directory as expected?

Comment: Are you using Docker Machine or Docker for Windows? In the tutorial the Docker volume is mapped to `.` on the host - but the host will be the Linux VM where Docker is running, not the Windows host.

Comment: I am using docker-toolbox and docker machine as I don't have Hyper-V (Win 10 Pro). So you're saying the mapped volume is somewhere inside the docker machine?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to uninstall Windows 10 and install a *nix system. The files then appear as per the tutorial.

```
~/docker/django-test $ ll
total 60
drwxr-xr-x  4096 Sep 24 00:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4096 Sep 24 00:40 ../
drwxr-xr-x  4096 Sep 24 00:47 composeexample/
-rw-r--r--   209 Sep 24 00:41 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r--   146 Sep 24 00:41 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x   812 Sep 24 00:47 manage.py*
-rw-r--r--    16 Sep 24 00:41 requirements.txt
```